# Why does x have to be all real values?

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let f(x) be any function with domain being all real x.

The functions E(x) and O(x) are defined as:
$$E(x)=(f(x)+f(-x))/2$$
$$O(x)=(f(x)-f(-x))/2$$
Also, $$f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$$
Investigate the importance of the domain (all real x) for f(x) and give a few examples demonstrating what can go wrong if the domain is not all real x.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When you ask about "the domain", which of the three functions are you asking about?

Comment: domain for f(x) is all real x

Comment: Assuming that you are not asking this because while you were walking down the street you picked up a paper that had only these three equations and the words "the domain is all real $x$", there is some additional context for this question that you know and have not told us, such as a course in which the statement came up, and anything else that was said before the statement that the domain is all real $x.$ I'm afraid you will have to say a lot more about the origin of this question in order to get a reliable reason why the domain should be so.

Comment: By the way, you should continue to **edit** the question in order to add any clarifications and context. Don't rely on people reading the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The domain does not have to be all real $x$. For example, your domain could just be $\{0\}$ and you could happily have your functions as $f(0) = 0$, $E(0) = 0$, $O(0) = 0$ (or maybe something else).

However, when you have a system of equations like this, it is more interesting to ask what your domain *could* be. In particular, on how large of a domain can you have functions which satisfy these equalities? Can you find functions which satisfy these equalities for all real $x$? Maybe if you require the domain to be all real $x$ you get a unique solution? These are questions that make the concept of the domain useful.

In this case, with a proper domain, these equations will hold true regardless of the $f$ you choose (by defining $E$ and $O$ as you did. However, a proper domain is crucial. For example, if you choose the domain of $f$ to be $[0,1]$, then you can't define $E(1)$, since $f(-1)$ is not defined! You will need your domain to be symmetric around $0$ (though not necessarily all real $x$), such as $[-1,1]$.

Comment: If the domain of $f$ were $[0,1]$ then the maximal domain that could be defined for $E$ or $O$ would be $\{0\}.$ Not very interesting, but it is a non-empty domain. If the domain of $f$ were $[1,\infty)$ then the other two functions would necessarily have empty domains. In other words, I think $f$ can have an asymmetric domain, but then the domains of $E$ and $O$ are smaller.

Comment: @DavidK Sure, but then the first equality would only make sense in the domain of $E$ and $O$. I guess I was assuming that the equality for $f$ had to hold in the domain of $f$, and similarly for the other two equations.

Comment: Good point, especially since we don't know where $f$ came from. It all comes back to the context of the question, about which we know almost nothing.